# How to compress elements inside a div

Tags: html, css

I have a div with this structure:

```
<div id="navigation">
    <a href="#">Overview</a>
    <a href="#">Test</a>
    <a href="#">test 2</a>
</div>
```

Which shows something like this:

[image]

Now, I have a jquery code to append elements inside "navigation. The problem is, I dont know how to make it look like this:

[image]

..especially if there are a lot of link tags.

Here is the css for "navigation"

```
#navigation{
    background: #efefef;
    height: 40px;
    width: 732px;
}
```

For the tags:

```
#navigation a{
   min-width: 108px;
   padding: 11px;
   display: inline-block;
   text-align: center;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need `max-width` instead of `min-width` for the links. Or, if you always want to space them evenly across the parent, just `width`.
This width needs to be calculated by you, because the browser can't do that by itself. In our example, there are 3 links, so the width of each link needs to be 100/3 = 33.3%.

Then some more styles, like text-overflow, to take care of the ellipsing, and you end up with this:

```
#navigation a{
   width: 33.3%;
   float:left;
   padding:11px;
   -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
   box-sizing:border-box;
   display:inline-block;
   text-align:center;
   white-space:nowrap;
   overflow:hidden;
   text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U28LL/3/)

As you can see, I also had to float them, to get rid of the spaces in between. If you don't want any floats, take the spaces into account when calculating the widths.

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP needs. From the image he provided he wants to add more links to the nav and for the menu to adapt dynamically. (I don't think this is possible though in css alone)

Comment: I think it is what the OP wants. "How to compress." The adding of new `a` elements itself with Javascript doesn't seem to be the problem, only the restricting of the width of each link and the ellipsis. Now if the number of links is known, all that needs to be done is to calculate the max width of each link.

Answer (score 0):

here is the [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/txDy8/3/)

```
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    }
body {
    font:normal 12px/18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#000;
    padding:20px;
    background-color:#F2F2F2;
    }
ul, li, ol {
    list-style-type:none;
    }

.wrapper {
    width:940px;
    padding:10px;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    border:1px  solid green;
    background-color:#3D3A40;
    border:8px solid #fff;
}
.spacer {
    clear:both;
    font-size:0;
    line-height:0;
    height:0;
    }
p {
    padding-bottom:18px;
    }

#navigation{
    background:#efefef;
    height:40px;
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:40px;
}
#navigation li {
    float:left;

    }
#navigation li a{
    padding:0 19px;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    color:#35B4DE;
    text-decoration:none;
    float:left;
}
#navigation li a:hover,
#navigation li a.active {
     background:#35B4DE;
    color:#fff;
    }
#navigation li span {
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    background-color:#FF0000;
    margin:13px  0 0 10px;
    display:block;
    float:right;
    }
#navigation li i.arrow {
    line-height:40px;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#35B4DE;
    display:block;
    float:right;
    padding:0 5px;
    }
#navigation li i.arrow a {
    padding:0;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#35B4DE;
    }
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#navigation li.icon a").append("<span></span>");
        $("#navigation li:last").append("<i class='arrow'><a href='#'>&raquo;</a></i>");
    });
</script>
```